# Delete row from MySQL based on values in two colums without using row ID

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When trying to execute the above, I get "operation should contain 1 column(s)" error.

This does not work:

```
DELETE FROM usernameRoutes.dbRoutes WHERE clientName='customer1',username='username01'
```

Is it possible to delete a row based on values in two columns?

Comment: Conditions must not be separated by commas. Use regular SQL syntax (`clientName='customer1' AND username='username01'`)

Comment: A good, basic SQL tutorial would be useful, as this is very basic SQL WHERE syntax. Your favorite search engine should be able to find one for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
DELETE FROM usernameRoutes.dbRoutes WHERE clientName='customer1' AND username='username01'
```

So, 'AND' instead of ','